# How to show that all even perfect numbers are obtained via Mersenne primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers, mersenne-numbers

A number $n$ is perfect if it's equal to the sum of its divisors (smaller than itself). A well known theorem by Euler states that every even perfect number is of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ where $2^p-1$ is prime (this is what is called a **Mersenne** prime).

How is this theorem proved? The converse (showing that every number of that form is perfect) is simple (the divisors of such a number are powers of 2 and powers of 2 times the Mersenne prime, and it's an easy sum to calculate) but I couldn't find a proof for the theorem itself.

Comment: [Here is a link to the Wikipedia page on the Euclid-Euler theorem on even perfect numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many elementary number theory texts have the proof, e.g., Hardy & Wright's.
[Here](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/EvenPerfect.html) is an online proof from Chris Caldwell's *Prime Pages*.